# Accessing to non contiguous slices in armadillo cube

Tags: rcpp, cube, armadillo

I find a way to select a subcube from a cube by taking some non contiguous cube. Is there a way without using loop? This is what I did for now.

```
cube f(vec a) {
 cube x(2,2,10,fill::randu);
 cube y(2,2,a.n_elem);
 for(int i(0); i<a.n_elem; ++i){
  y.slice(i) = x.slice(a(i));
 }
 return y;
}
```

Comment: I would have thought [the subcube `elem()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube) may help but it doesn't seem so.  But what you have works ... so good enough, maybe?

Comment: Clearer to me now what `elem()` -- it views the `cube` as a vector and indexes that.

Comment: There's no way to do this with a built-in armadillo function now. Furthermore, I wouldn't be too worried about loops in _C++_ as they do not carry the overhead associated with _R_.

Comment: Ok thank you to all. I will keep the loop above

Comment: There is also [.each_slice()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_slice)

Comment: Hi @mtall, I check .each_slice(), but I think it is not possible to replicate the example above with that. May be it is possible, can you check for me?